# Class coverage is 0%

Tags: deployment, change-set, failing-tests

I am moving my classes from Sandbox to Production. All the classes have a minimum coverage of 80% in my sandbox. The change set contains both my Apex class and the test class. But in my production, I'm getting an error `Your code coverage is 0%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment.`

I also don't have any unexpected required fields or validations in my production. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is this the only error you have?

Comment: It's maybe a really dumb proposition, but check you putted the tests list comma separated. This happens to me sometimes if i'm not really focused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here was the mistake I was doing. I used `Run Specified Tests` to validate my classes and I was adding only the test classes that were needed to move my apex classes to production. But the customer had introduced some validations directly into his production environment and hadn't updated his existing test classes. This made the existing test classes obsolete and they were throwing an error.

I found this when I deployed the change set with `Default` as my option to validate the test classes and here all the test classes were executed and the error was thrown.

Answer (score 3):

I used Specified Tests Option while deploying.

we need to make sure that Test classes are separated by commas

TestclassA,
TestClassB,
TestClassC

If they are not separated by comas, it may result above error.

Comment: Correct! Some people put all the test classes in a separate line ( under Run Specified Tests) which also causes the same error!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check all dependency, static resource and also check the field you are using in apex class exist in production or not

Comment: I am not using any static resource. But yeah, all the fields and the dependencies exist

Comment: please make sure about all dependency, when we have some dependency its always show 0% coverage

Comment: Yogesh, all the dependencies were in place. I've posted what the issue was. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply run all tests when deploying. It happened to me as well. I guess it's a Salesforce bug/feature.

Comment: Yup, instead of running all tests, I'd given the option as Default. I didn't mark this as the answer as I wanted everyone else to know the mistake I was doing. Anyway, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I simply haven't removed test classes file extensions from the RunSpecifiedTests files list.

So for example, instead of `TestClassOne, TestClassTwo, TestClassThree` I had `TestClassOne.cls, TestClassTwo.cls, TestClassThree.cls`. The files have to be listed comma separated and the without file extension.